# Show 10 latest posts only from users with contributors role

Tags: posts, sidebar, query, user-roles, list

How to achive this in sidebar.List of 10 latest permalinks(post titles) from contributors ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `author` parameter of [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters)

here is a simple function to get you going with a hook to a shortcode and another hook to render this shortcode inside a simple text widget:

```
function ten_latest_of_contributers($atts = null){
global $post;
//store the current post data
$temp = $post;
$contributors = get_users(array('role'=> 'contributor'));
//then create an array of contributors ids

$contributors_ids = array();
foreach ($contributors as $user) {
    $contributors_ids[] =  $user->ID;
}

//then create a new query and use the author parameter
$con_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'author' => implode( ',', $contributors_ids ),
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10));

//all that is left is to loop
$re = '<ul>';
while($con_query->have_posts()){
    $con_query->the_post();
    $re .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</a></li>';
}
$re .= '</ul>';
//reset the current post data
wp_reset_postdata();
$post = $temp;

//return the list
return $re;
}
// hook your shortcode
add_shortcode('ten_latest_con','ten_latest_of_contributers');

//render shortcodes in widgets
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

Paste this code in your theme's functions.php and then just enter `[ten_latest_con]` inside a text widget.

Comment: Internal Server Error when i put code in functions.php

Comment: Create a pastebin of your functions.php

Comment: http://pastebin.com/33hYM0DF

Comment: Ok i've updated the code, there were a few syntax errors but now its tested and works fine.

Comment: tnx, I will try this code, but Im curious about insert small excerpt toghether with post titles, and maybe user photo also..Is this hard task to accomplish?

Comment: No its not hard if you know what you're doing

Comment: Can you help me with this?

Comment: help in code for you ?

Comment: Could I put in loop excerpt tag, and for photo, tag from some plugin which get user photo for me?

Comment: anything you can use in a template file will work here, tags, shortcodes loops whatever you want